# Microsoft Word Automated Find and Replace feature

Tags: excel, ms-word, office-automation

In a Microsoft template file I downloaded from their website, whenever you type any word in place of where it says " < your company > " (for instance, if I type the word "Apple" in it's place), it automatically changes it everywhere within the entire document. So anywhere in the document that says " < your company > ", it will now all be changed to "Apple".

Does anyone know how to create that?

It seems like some pre-programmed and automated "Find & Replace" feature, but I don't know how to create it. Does it involve some external Excel file? I don't think it's a macro, because " < your company > " is replaced by text that is entered, not a pre-determined word.

---

This video kind of addresses what I'm trying to achieve. But it's not quite perfect because it's talking about a "find and replace" for multiple Word files, and for replacing the text with a pre-determined word (not what the user enters):

www.youtube.com/watch?v=etSoe8P7_PE

---

The Word file I'm referring to can be downloaded from my dropbox here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b8hg0ahbx27wfij/CdlGP_bdcm

If you don't feel comfortable downloading a file from my dropbox: I downloaded this file from Microsoft's website, so if you want to download it directly from there, you can via the link below. It seems like the link won't take you directly to the file, so you just have to enter "project change" in the search bar and click enter, then download the Word 2013 "Project change authorization form (Business Blue design)" file:

[http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/results.aspx?qu=project%20change&queryid=13f05805-9704-404a-911b-c3cd70c3fe5c&avg=zwd#ai:TC103444179|](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/results.aspx?qu=project%20change&queryid=13f05805-9704-404a-911b-c3cd70c3fe5c&avg=zwd#ai%3aTC103444179|)

---

Thank you so much for your time and help!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# word interop find and replace everything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252252/c-sharp-word-interop-find-and-replace-everything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you look for :

[Find and Replace using Word interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252252/c-sharp-word-interop-find-and-replace-everything)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not a programmer or coder at all... so I don't know what to do with all that code that is on the page you sent a link to? And I'm also not sure how I would customize it to suit my document. Meaning, if I want people to enter their own name in " < Client Name > " (and then have their name appear anywhere in the document that says " < Client Name > "), how would I customize the code for that?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer: The first section of code is a method which enables to find and replace programmatically. The second code section invokes this method. You do not have to understand the content of method but to send appropriate parameters ("Company Name and Apple, as example). Any other help?

Comment: First of all create a project and ass the Interop Word reference (right click on the project icon -> Add reference -> in GAC tab you should find `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` and in the COM tab add the `Microsoft Office <num> Word` Object Library ), then add the second section of code from my link: this code creates a Word application, opens the document you want to modify and invokes the find and replace option.

Comment: How things are going? Need any other help?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the OP's template lives at https://templates.office.com/en-us/Services-proposal-Business-Blue-design-TM02911896

It is using content controls (forms), which are accessible under the developer tab of the ribbon. Click "Design Mode" to view the magic.